# Threshold optimization with two parameters where first parameter need to be minimum and second value to be maximum

Tags: mathematical-statistics, calculus, differential-equations

We have threshold values ranging from 1 to 10 where attributes p1, p2 increase with increase in threshold. Our intention is to find threshold with  minimum p1 and maximum p2. It would be of great help if we could get any suggestion or answer to this problem.

Comment: This is quite vague, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on asking a good quality question. What are p1 and p2? Are they the data before thresholding or some metric post-thresholding?

Comment: p1 is false positive rate which needs to be minimum and p2 is replica rate which needs to be maximum.